# Unable to scrape buybox price from amazon

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract price from Amazon PDP https://www.amazon.co.uk/SheaMoisture-Treatment-silicone-sulphate-transitioning/dp/B01HOD3ZVQ/ by selenium chrome web driver.

Tried:

1. X path
2. CSS selector
3. Find all method
4. Found that javascript is blocking price to be scraped but that is also not working or I have not identified proper js.

I am referring to attached price shown in below screenshot.

[buybox price ss][1]

```
            try:
                # Wait for the "Price" element to be present using WebDriverWait
                price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "apexPriceToPay")]/span[contains(@class, "a-offscreen")]'))
                    #EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div"]/div/div/span[1]/span[1]'))
                    #EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corePrice_feature_div"]/div/div/span[1]/span[1]'))
                )


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIn1M.png
```

Comment: We love that you're here with us. What does "it is not working for me" mean, precisely? How can we help?

Comment: buybox price is not getting extracted with this python script.
url: https://www.amazon.co.uk/SheaMoisture-Treatment-silicone-sulphate-transitioning/dp/B01HOD3ZVQ/

Comment: Has it occurred to you that they do this on purpose?  They don't want bots knowing their prices.  If you figure out a way around it they'll come up with something new.

Comment: What is this "buybox" price that you are referring to? A screenshot highlighting the specific price you are referring to would be helpful. Also please provide a [mcve]... you've included too much code irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: No other paid tools are able to extract that then there should be a way I can also do it. Other information, I was able to extract out easily but with price I am facing issues. Also, updated the code with minimal requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

here i use Edge, you can use chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
import time

options = Options()

driver_service = Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=driver_service, options=options)


driver.get(f"https://www.amazon.co.uk/SheaMoisture-Treatment-silicone-sulphate-transitioning/dp/B01HOD3ZVQ/")

time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds


# Extract RRP
rrp_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-text-price[data-a-color='secondary']")
rrp = rrp_element.text

# Extract Price
price_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.apexPriceToPay")
price = price_element.text

# Extract Savings
savings_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(), 'You Save:')]/following-sibling::td/span[@class='a-color-price']")
savings = savings_element.text

# Extract Price per 100 ml
price_per_100ml_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.aok-relative span.a-color-price")
price_per_100ml = price_per_100ml_element.text

print(f"RRP: {rrp}")
print(f"Price: {price}")
print(f"You Save: {savings}")
print(f"Price per 100 ml: {price_per_100ml}")
```

Comment: Thanks, @AariyanPatel for showing the approach. I am now able to get the result, though some in some url changes are required but I learned now. Thanks again!!